# Objext of DBContext not getting initialized within a class in ASP.NET core using EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have initialized Dbcontext in my project and now I am trying the fetch the data using DBContext object in a class using its constructor, but it's not getting initialized and the object is having null value.

```
{
    public SSIMContext(DbContextOptions<SSIMContext> DBdata) :
        base(DBdata)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ScvCertificate> ScvCertificates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReconcileRequests> ReconcileRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ResponseToDF> ResponseToDF { get; set; }
}
```

//Registration of SSIMContext in startup.cs

```
        services.AddDbContextPool<SSIMContext>(
            data => data.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdracDBConnection")));
```

//Fetching data for dbcontext in controller is working as expected but same approach is not working in a normal class

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebCoreHSMAPI.Models;

namespace WebCoreHSMAPI.DataAccessLayer
{
    public class GetResponseMessages
    {
       public static SSIMContext _context;
      
        public GetResponseMessages(SSIMContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public static List<ResponseToDF> GetResponseMessage(string MessageType,string ProcessingNode)
        {
            try
            {

                    List<ResponseToDF> ResponseToDF = _context.ResponseToDF.FromSqlRaw("UP_GET_RESPONSEDATA {0},{1}", MessageType, ProcessingNode).ToList();
                    return ResponseToDF;
                
             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Calling method in this way:

```
 public static void GetMessages(string MessageType,string ProcessingNode)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ResponseToDF> response = GetResponseMessages.GetResponseMessage(MessageType, ProcessingNode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any help on this will be appreciated..Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you instantiate `GetResponseMessages`? (Which, IMO, is a misnomer. Classes are *things* that *do* stuff so they should have a noun as name, not a verb. Their methods are verbs.)

Comment: @Rena It did not work for me as you suggested, I will post the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are not instanciating the `GetResponseMessages` class by dependency injection most probably (or at all).

You would need to add it as a service.

Share the code where you use it for us to help some more.

My bet is that you use the static method directly

```
GetResponseMessages.GetResponseMessage(/*...*/)
```

You should change the signature to

```
public List<ResponseToDF> GetResponseMessage(string MessageType,string ProcessingNode)
```

And use an instance of the class.

Comment: I have added the way i am calling the method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

```
services.AddDbContext<SSIMContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString")));

var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SSIMContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString"));

services.AddSingleton(new GetResponseMessages(optionsBuilder.Options));
```

DbContext:

```
public class SSIMContext: DbContext
{
    public SSIMContext(DbContextOptions<SSIMContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
 
    public DbSet<TestModel> Test{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In program.cs file I added these lines to configure dbcontextfactory (marked as**)

```
    namespace SSIMToDFMessaging
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    **string connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("IdracDBConnection").Value;**
                    services.AddHostedService<SSIMToDFMessagingService>();
                    **services.AddDbContextFactory<SSIMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString))**;

                });
    }
}
```

In the service i am fetching the instance this way

```
 SSIMContext _context;
      public SSIMToDFMessagingService(ILogger<SSIMToDFMessagingService> logger, IDbContextFactory<SSIMContext> dbContextFactory, IConfiguration _config)
        {
            
            // _logger = logger;
            **_context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();**
            // dbContextFactory1 = dbContextFactory;
            configuration = _config;

        }
```